# Passing advanced search query from html form

Tags: html, forms, google-search, advanced-search

I'm trying to pass a couple of search queries (allintitle and allinurl) from an HTML form to Google. I tried to use the example found below by inserting these parameters (as_occt=title and as_occt=url) but wasn't able to get it to work.

```
        <form action="https://google.com/search">
           All these words:<input type="text" name="as_q" >
           <br><br>Exact word/phrase:<input type="text" name="as_epq" >
           <br><br>Any of these words:<input type="text" name="as_oq" >
           <br><br>None of these words:<input type="text" name="as_eq" >
           <br><br> 
           <input type="submit" value="advanced search">
        </form>
```

Comment: It is not possible to pass for searching to `google.com/serach` because the address is for searching from the google website's search filed.

Comment: But you can open google search page with an address which is a result after searching by building script.

Comment: `https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=${TheKeyword}`